# Problematic parsed JSON object format. How to decode JSON object below in Swift 5?

Tags: json, xcode, parsing, format, swift5

```
{
    0 =     {
        bitrate = 320;
        dloadUrl = "www.example.com";
        mp3size = "20.1 MB";
    };
    1 =     {
        bitrate = 256;
        dloadUrl = "www.example.com";
        mp3size = "16.08 MB";
    };
    2 =     {
        bitrate = 192;
        dloadUrl = "www.example.com";
        mp3size = "12.06 MB";
    };
    3 =     {
        bitrate = 128;
        dloadUrl = "www.example.com";
        mp3size = "8.04 MB";
    };
    4 =     {
        bitrate = 64;
        dloadUrl = "www.example.com";
        mp3size = "4.02 MB";
    };
}
```

Trying to decode API response I got, and having troubles with decoding. Looks like the format is not quite what JSON object would have. Please help, I am relatively new to coding. I am using xcode and writing in swift 5.

Comment: Actually thats not a valid json, you can learn by using: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a valid json. A valid json, in your case, would be:

```
{
    "0": {
        "bitrate": 320,
        "dloadUrl": "www.example.com",
        "mp3size": "20.1 MB"
    },
    "1": {
        "bitrate": 256,
        "dloadUrl": "www.example.com",
        "mp3size": "16.08 MB"
    },
    "2": {
        "bitrate": 192,
        "dloadUrl": "www.example.com",
        "mp3size": "12.06 MB"
    },
    "3": {
        "bitrate": 128,
        "dloadUrl": "www.example.com",
        "mp3size": "8.04 MB"
    },
    "4": {
        "bitrate": 64,
        "dloadUrl": "www.example.com",
        "mp3size": "4.02 MB"
    }
}
```

And you would decode like:

```
struct MyJson: Codable {
    let bitrate: Int
    let dloadUrl: String
    let mp3size: String
}

let json = ...
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let res = try decoder.decode([Int: MyJson].self, from data)
    print(res)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```